# How can i optimaly send a drawing via websocket?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, canvas, websocket

I'm currently working on an online pictionnary (one person do a drawing and the others have to guess what it is).

Currently i'm sending my entire image from the drawer (in a canvas) base64 on the "mouseup" DOM event to the server and i send it back to the guesser in the same format, my problem is that it seems pretty heavy and i have no idea how to have a lighter payload.

```
$('#canvas').on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    mouse.down = false;

    // My problem is sending canvas.toDataURL() every time
    update_canvas(canvas.toDataURL());
});

// I use this function inside ActionCable so this.perform will send the data to my channel
var update_canvas = function(data_url) {
    this.perform('update_canvas', {data_url: data_url});
},
```

Do you have a better way to send my image data ?

Comment: Have you looked into better ways to do that? There may be too many of them to be covered here. Have you also measured network latencies with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

You could either send a list of mouse positions or incremental changes of the canvas, i.e send only new drawings using a second canvas.

Comment: That's a good approach. An basic implementation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705140/3702797)

Answer (score 0):

Well i think the best approach would be to send the coordinates you are drawing, i have implemented a similar kind of thing, u cn hv a look
http://connectboard.herokuapp.com/
open it in two or more different browser or computer and draw.